# Как снять ограничение  a.options.videos[0].title?

Tags: javascript

Наткнулся на ограничение по названию (вывод видео). Вписываешь другое название, и видео не показывается. Не пойму, как его можно снять.

```
PLAYER.Playlist = function(c, e, b, g, h, f, d, r, t, n, u, v, w, x) {
    function q(c) {
        "youtube" == b.videos[0].videoType && (a.VIDEO.removeHTML5elements(), "Yes" == b.loadRandomVideoOnStart ? a.youtubePlayer.cueVideoById(a.videos_array[a.rand].youtubeID) : a.youtubePlayer.cueVideoById(a.videos_array[0].youtubeID), this.hasTouch || b.autoplay && a.youtubePlayer.playVideo(), a.VIDEO.resizeAll(), n && "Ferrari" != a.options.videos[0].title && "Ferrari" != a.options.videos[0].title && "Ferrari" !=
            a.options.videos[0].title && "Ferrari" != a.options.videos[0].title && "Ferrari" != a.options.videos[0].title && "Ferrari" != a.options.videos[0].title && "Ferrari" != a.options.youtubeChannelID && (a.VIDEO.pw(), void 0 != a.youtubePlayer && (a.youtubePlayer.stopVideo(), a.youtubePlayer.clearVideo(), a.youtubePlayer.setSize(1, 1))))
    }
```

Comment: Вот это адъ :)

Comment: Поскольку никто не ответил, остается вариант оставить, только вписывать нужные мне title. 

Я так понял, что существует зависимость  && "Ferrari" != a.options.videos[0].title и title в файле index.php....

Comment: @Serg1234, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести, откуда у вас этот код и где именно вы пытаетесь изменить название.